# Regex formula validation for multiple possible string inputs

Tags: regex

Require some help with building Regex formula to validate input string.

Below is my formula that I've come with so far but some parts does not work as per required.

[image]

Requirements:-

Acceptable Input String

- Mandatory Character Length between 8,16
- Mandatory String Content Alphanumeric with 1 minimum Alpha --> Does not work
- Optional Special Characters ._-  --> Does not work

Samples:

```
 -'11910281 --> Not Match'    
 -'9U910281 --> Match'    
 -'BC189201 --> Match'    
 -'BC189201.01 --> Match'    
 -'BC189201_01 --> Match'      
 -'BC189201-01 --> Match'
```

**OR** String as below

```
 MTMBX|MTTBX|MTRBX|MTRBX|MTREJ
```

Not Acceptable Input String With Prefix

```
 GMSS|GTSS|GRRT|REJS
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What problems did you run into?

Comment: Also, those strings provided already match the rules you give above, what do they add? The "not allowed" strings do add a condition, but what do you mean by "with prefix". Please provide some examples of strings you're looking to match and strings that shouldn't be matched - and a code example of what you tried.

Comment: Grismar, I'm not writing a code but rather trying to come out with a Regex formula. I have provided that formula that I've came out with but some part still does not fulfil the requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
^(?!GMSS|GTSS|GRRT|REJS)(?:(?=[^A-Z\s]*[A-Z])[A-Z0-9._-]{8,16}|MTMBX|MTTBX|MTRBX|MTRBX|MTREJ)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!GMSS|GTSS|GRRT|REJS)` Negative lookahead, assert not any of the alternatives
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?=[^A-Z\s]*[A-Z])` Positive lookahead, assert at least a single char A-Z
  - `[A-Z0-9._-]{8,16}` Match any of the listed 8-16 times
  - `|` Or
  - `MTMBX|MTTBX|MTRBX|MTRBX|MTREJ` Match any of the allowed alternatives
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7gRAM8/1)